# Relationship between $E(Y|X=E(X))$ and $E(Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I note that when $(X,Y)$ are bivariate normal, $E(Y|X=E(X))=E(Y)$. So I wonder: is there a general relationship that exists between $E(Y|X=E(X))$ and $E(Y)$? What are some sufficient conditions to guarantee $E(Y|X=E(X))=E(Y)$?

To start, I assume $X,Y,(X,Y)$ have densities $f_X$, $f_Y$ and $f_{(X,Y)}$. Then
\begin{align}
E(Y|X=E(X))=\int y\frac{f_{(X,Y)}(E(X),y)}{f_X(E(X))}dy.
\end{align}
In the trivial case that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $f_{(X,Y)}(E(X),y)$ factors into $f_X(E(X))f_Y(y)$ and we do have $E(Y|X=E(X))=E(Y)$. But I can't simplify further for the general case.

Comment: $E(Y\mid X)=f(X)$, hence you want $f(E(X))=E(f(X))$. This certainly holds for all linear $f$, as noted in the answer below, but not only. You do know that $g$ can't be strictly convex/concave unless $X$ is constant.

Comment: @A.S. Can you turn that into an answer? I find it quite satisfactory for my question.

Answer (score 1):

One situation leading to that conclusion: $E(Y|X=x)=a+bx$ for all $x$, for certain constants $a$ and $b$. (I am assuming that both $X$ and $Y$ have finite means.) In this case we must have $E(Y) = a+bE(X)$, and so
$E(Y|X=x)=E(Y)+b(x-E(X))$ for all $x$.

Comment: The bivariate normal belongs to your general specification.